# PostgreSQL:How can I solve this?

Tags: postgresql, macos

I am installing PostgreSQL (Ver12 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6). Before it finishes installing, I am getting the following error:

> Usually this means that there is already a PostgreSQL server running
> on your Mac. If you want to run multiple servers simultaneously, use
> different ports.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you installed the pg package, from which source, include that information please.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the course at udemy
https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-sql-masterclass-for-data-analytics

Comment: Not looking for instructions, there are multiple source from EDB, postgres, homebrew can be used to install postgresql. To help you fix, which source you are using will be helpful information.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql by default run on port `5432`. On your system, port `5432` is already in use using separate process, probably Postgresql running from previous installation. When the installer you are using is trying to install the server and start up, it can not because of the default `5432` port not being free. Installer like the provided by [EDB](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) automatically detects free port for example 5432,5433,5434... and runs the server on available one.

You can get running postgres process information using `ps aux|grep` postgres.